# Swagger: Add fields to all endpoints

Tags: swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

Is there a way to add default fields to all of my end-points?
I wish to add fields like api_key, sort, limit etc. to all of my end points.

Can you add a set of default input parameters to all end points in a central location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define Parameters like

```
"parameters": {
"skipParam": {
  "name": "skip",
  "in": "query",
  "description": "number of items to skip",
  "required": true,
  "type": "integer",
  "format": "int32"
},
```

and then use it like

```
 "parameters": [
      { "$ref": "#/parameters/skipParam" }
],
```

Using this, you will not have to specify parameter details again and again but will need to add ref where required.

More details can be found at [Open Api Specification](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/fixtures/v2.0/json/resources/reusableParameters.json)

Comment: Thanks Bilal. I will give it go.